# Apple LLVM 6.0 Error UICollectionView

Tags: uicollectionview

I control drag CollectionView from storyBoard to ViewController.h like this

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

After Build, Xcode has an Apple LLVM 6.0 Error below.

file '/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/alpha003/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1MBMXMEEES6H1/UIKit-14NGSGHI2IEK1.pcm' was built

It doesn't happened before. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete this file `/Users/alpha003/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1MBMXMEEES6H1/UIKit-14NGSGHI2IEK1.pcm`.

After you rebuild your project, the *.pcm files under ModuleCache directory will recreated in right way.

The reason is you have modified the system framework header files.

Comment: It works, i have experienced the same issue but with the UITableViewController. I'm wondering how i change the system framework header files. I'm doing normal stuffs. Anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the error only occur when Deployment Target is 7.0

Other Deployment Target like 6.0 or 7.1 worked just fine.

Although I still can't find out what's going on?